# npm audit fix - Returns same message, doesn't fix anything

Tags: node.js, npm

We are running `npm audit fix` - But it just keeps returning the same message:

```
8 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix
```

`npm audit fix` doesn't resolve any issues. What's going wrong here?

Comment: Maybe the vulnerabilities are not fixed in the most recent versions of those packages. Or the versions that are fixed cannot be used (they may be fixed in different major versions and the upgrade is not possible using the declared dependency versions). It is impossible to answer without knowing what are the vulnerable packages and how are they required in your project. You should add in the question the content of `.dependencies`, `.devDependencies`, `.peerDependencies` and `.optionalDependencies` sections of your `package.json`.

Comment: Thanks - My question is about the text: `To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix` --> Surely this is wrong, if it's dependent and won't address *all* issues (such as dependency version issues)?